# What are the uses of being able to refer to an environment body by a macro?

Tags: environments

The packages `environ` and `newenviron` both provide an alternative to the standard environment macros included with LaTeX.  The main difference is that they make it possible to refer to the environment body using a macro, but another difference is that macro expansion is affected. If it weren't for this effect the only other thing these packages would seem to be good for is when you need to refer to an environment body multiple times. Are there any other uses for being able to refer to the environment body by macro?

Comment: Any time when you want to be able to manipulate the contents of the environment body or gain information about it before typesetting (cf `align` and friends and the measuring business for example)

Comment: Or want to apply something that is intrinsically taking an argument to the body of a macro: `\uppercase` for example.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a 'big-list'?

Answer (score 2):

You can for instance measure the environment body and perform different things depending on this measurments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newenviron,lipsum}
\newdimen\hkBstheight
\newenviron{hkBstEnv}{%
  \setbox0=\vbox{\hkBstEnvbody}
  \hkBstheight=\ht0
  \advance\hkBstheight by \dp0
  \ifdim\hkBstheight<200pt
    {\itshape\hkBstEnvbody}
  \else
    \hkBstEnvbody
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{hkBstEnv}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{hkBstEnv}

\begin{hkBstEnv}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{hkBstEnv}
\end{document}
```