# Extensions to the standard environment, what is out there?

Tags: environments

`\NewDocumentEnvironment` from the `xparse` package allows accessing environment arguments also in the code that is supposed to go after the content.

`environ` and `newenviron` allow referring to the environment body by macro.

What other extensions of the standard environment are out there and what are they good for?

Comment: this is the same https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254615/what-are-the-uses-of-being-able-to-refer-to-an-environment-body-by-a-macro no? if yes you can edit your first question

Comment: @touhami: That other question is specifically asking what the uses are of referring to an environment body as a macro. This one is asking about other extensions to environments and their uses and merely lists some examples.

Comment: ok i am sorry i didn't understand well

Comment: There's also fancyvrb's `VerbatimOut` to write the content to a file (then you can do anything with the file, but requires a temporary file), and `scontents` which saves the content verbatim in memory (although I didn't figure out how to use it) see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513810/250119